# elastic bean stalk failed to deploy with docker-compose, failed with error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have dockerised a .net application. The Dockerfile is inside the app folder and not in the root of repository

docker file is pasted below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["app/app.csproj", "app/"]
RUN dotnet restore "app/app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/app"
RUN dotnet build "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

to make Elastic Beanstalk read the dockerfile I have put the following docker-compose.yml in the root of repository

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
```

Beanstalk is building the dockerimage successfully but after that it is removed. The eb-engine.log is showing the Error

```
[ERROR] update processes [cfn-hup eb-docker-compose-events docker eb-docker-events healthd eb-docker-compose-log] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you find any workarounds/fixes for this? I'm running into this error right now.

Comment: I guess instead of docker file I used Dockerrun.aws.json and specified the image name there.

Comment: That makes sense but wouldn't work for me. I needed to migrate my `Dockerrun.aws.json` contents to a `docker-compose.yml` file in order to get off of the Elastic Beanstalk deprecated Multi-container Docker platform and onto the newer Docker Linux 2 platform.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same

```
[ERROR] update processes [cfn-hup eb-docker-compose-events docker eb-docker-events healthd eb-docker-compose-log] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory
```

error happening for my Docker Compose app (not using `.net`) when trying to deploy it to my Elastic Beanstalk environment.

I found a way to fix this which is probably specific to me, but I hope it can help you solve your problem *(as I'm sure your solution might be similar, or potentially completely different)*. I already answered this (with slight tweaks) [on this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71114053/1180523), but posting it here in hopes it helps you and future devs facing a similar problem.

---

##### What caused the error for me:

This `...eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file...` error was a false error triggered by a separate issue with my application code not finding the environment variables setup in my Elastic Beanstalk environment. See below for how I found the problem, and what I did to fix it.

---

##### How I found my real problem:

I downloaded the **Full Logs** and stumbled across a different error *(which wasn't shown in the logs for the `Last 100 lines`)*:

1. go to your EB environment
2. click `Logs` on the left nav
3. click the `Request Logs` dropdown button *(at the top right)*
4. click `Full Logs`
5. click the `Download` link once the full logs are ready

Inside of the logs, I found the real problem in the `eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-stdouterr.log` file, the issue being that my application code wasn't able to find the environment variables that I setup in my Elastic Beanstalk Software configuration.

In case you're curious what my error said:

```golang
panic: required key ONE_OF_MY_ENV_KEYS missing value
```

*(I also had a couple other errors in this log that I fixed first, but fixing the error shown above is what ended up solving the `...eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file...` problem for me)*.

---

##### How I fixed this error:

It turns out that if you use `docker-compose.yml`, while setting up your environment variables in your Elastic Beanstalk Software configuration, you have to make sure you use the `.env` file that Elastic Beanstalk creates for you; otherwise *(from my own testing)*, EB only see's/uses the environment variable keys/values you specify in your own `.env` file or `environment:` list you can specify in `docker-compose.yml`.

**NOTE:** see the Elastic Beanstalk **"Environment properties and Environment Variables"** and **"Referencing environment variables in containers"** sections in [the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-software-config.env), in particular this bit:

> "Elastic Beanstalk generates a Docker Compose environment file called `.env` in the root directory of your application project. This file stores the environment variables you configured for Elastic Beanstalk.
>
> **Note**
> If you include a `.env` file in your application bundle, Elastic Beanstalk will not generate an `.env` file."

I solved my problem by updating my `docker-compose.yml` file to point to the supposed `.env` file that EB would create for me *(by adding `env_file: .env` to my services that needed it)*, i.e.:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  my_service1:
    # ...
    env_file: .env
  my_service2:
    # ...
    env_file: .env
```

Comment: Kudos for reading the entirety of the docs. This helped me.