# Deploying simple docker app with docker-compose on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple docker app that is able to run for me locally via `docker-compose up`, and when I send the `.yml` file to my friend, they are also able to get it up and running on their local machine. However, when I try to deploy it on Elastic Beanstalk, I get errors (specifically, something related to `error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory`, as I'll show below). I've tried to upload multiple times to Elastic Beanstalk, with the same errors. This is a custom app, but they are the same errors I got when I was trying to follow the instructions on `https://docker-curriculum.com/#docker-on-aws`. Here is the `docker-compose.yml` for my current app:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: mfatigati/shop-server
    container_name: shop-server
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
  client:
    image: mfatigati/shop-client
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

`mfatigati/shop-server` and `mfatigati/shop-client` are both Node.JS apps, i.e., `FROM node:16` in their `Dockerfile`.

To deploy this on AWS, I go to my EB console, and then:

1. Click "Create Application" to take me to the create app screen
2. Choose "Docker" as the platform
3. Choose "Upload local code", and upload the above-mentioned `.yml` file.
4. Click "Create Application"

Based on the notes [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html), I think this should be all I need to do (maybe I'm wrong about that?), but I get errors every time that point me to the `eb.engine.log` file. I've pasted what seems to be the relevant section below, as it is the only section that mentions errors, and it also reflects what appears in the AWS GUI console. The main problem seems reflected by the bit about `error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory`:

```
2022/02/14 14:17:23.619888 [ERROR] update processes [cfn-hup eb-docker-events healthd eb-docker-compose-events eb-docker-compose-log docker] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory
2022/02/14 14:17:23.619901 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Track pids in healthd]. Stop running the command. Error: update processes [cfn-hup eb-docker-events healthd eb-docker-compose-events eb-docker-compose-log docker] pid symlinks failed with error Read pid source file /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid failed with error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory 

2022/02/14 14:17:23.619905 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2022/02/14 14:17:23.620005 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1644848243,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! I'm pasting some screenshots below, in case that helps.

[GUI corresponding to step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4AgD.png); [GUI corresponding to step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zca.png); [GUI errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXu6C.png)

Comment: I'm having this problem now, did you find any workarounds/fixes?

Comment: I actually am just revisiting all this this week! I was finally able to get past the above stage when I realized that being on an M1 mac means that I needed to build my images differently, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361936/exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error-in-aws-fargate-service). Another problem with the above is that I needed to have the client available on port 80 of my EB environment (so `80:3000`. But that is unrelated to the above error. Still dealing with an `Invalid Host header` problem with I try to access the app on EB, but that's something new :/

Comment: ok   I just solved the problem causing my `error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory ` error. I'm not sure if the reason will be the same, but I'll post what ended up working for me, I hope it helps you! 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same `error:open /var/pids/eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file or directory` error happening for my Docker Compose app when trying to deploy it to my Elastic Beanstalk environment; I'm not sure if my solution will be the same solution you need, but I hope it points you in the right direction *(and helps future devs facing a similar problem)*.

---

##### What caused the error for me:

This `...eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file...` error was a false error that was triggered by a separate issue; my separate error was actually a problem with my application code not finding the environment variables set in my Elastic Beanstalk environment. See below for how I found the problem, and what I did to fix it.

---

##### How I found my real problem:

I downloaded the **Full Logs:**

1. go to your EB environment
2. click `Logs` on the left nav
3. click the `Request Logs` dropdown button *(at the top right)*
4. click `Full Logs`
5. click the `Download` link once the full logs are ready

Inside of the logs, I found the real problem in the `eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-stdouterr.log` file, the issue being that my application code wasn't able to find the environment variables that were setup in my Elastic Beanstalk Software configuration.

In case you're curious what my error said:

```golang
panic: required key ONE_OF_MY_ENV_KEYS missing value
```

*(I also had a couple other errors in this log that I fixed, but fixing the error shown above is what ended up solving the `...eb-docker-compose-log.pid: no such file...` error)*.

---

##### How I fixed this error:

I turns out that if you use `docker-compose.yml`, while setting up your environment variables in your Elastic Beanstalk Software configuration, you have to make sure you use the `.env` file that Elastic Beanstalk creates for you; otherwise *(from my own testing)*, EB only see's/uses the environment variable keys/values you specify in your own `.env` file or `environment:` list you can specify in `docker-compose.yml`.

**NOTE:** see the Elastic Beanstalk **"Environment properties and Environment Variables"** and **"Referencing environment variables in containers"** sections in [the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-software-config.env), in particular this bit:

> "Elastic Beanstalk generates a Docker Compose environment file called `.env` in the root directory of your application project. This file stores the environment variables you configured for Elastic Beanstalk.
>
> **Note**
> If you include a `.env` file in your application bundle, Elastic Beanstalk will not generate an `.env` file."

I solved my problem by updating my `docker-compose.yml` file to point to the supposed `.env` file that EB would create for me *(by adding `env_file: .env` to my services that needed it)*, i.e.:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  my_service1:
    # ...
    env_file: .env
  my_service2:
    # ...
    env_file: .env
```